# Proposing variables list - php

Tags: php, variables, aptana

Aptana 3, on MAC OS X 10.6.x using a MAMP local server.
Coding php
I have several files in the project and using the same variables in several files.  Go to type $ and then want to see a list of proposals that includes the variables in all the files of the project as I type.

Say file "A" has the var $bob and I start coding in file "B".  I type $b and the list does not show $bob as a proposal of possible vars to select.

Netbeans has this behavior, but Aptana and apparently, Eclipse with the PHP plugin does not either.

What am I missing?  Is this a "as designed" behavior, or am I not configuring something correctly?

Thanks,

-John

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it, and it works for me (using the latest Aptana Studio 3, nightly build).

I've created a file a.php and added a `$bob=1;` to it. Then created b.php and got the code assist for `$bob` when I typed `$b`.

Since I'm in charge of developing the `PHP` editor, I know for sure that we don't limit the code assist to the currently edited module. We allow proposals from other resources in the project (or any other attached resource through the 'PHP Buildpath' (in the project properties).

Try to clean your project, as something may have happen to corrupt the index - Do a Project -> Clean and select 'Clean All'. This will re-build the PHP index from scratch.

Also, click Help->Aptana Studio -> View Log File and keep the log open in the editor. Try to trigger the code assist and then go back to the log to see if there are any new errors.

Let me know if you still have this issue.
Cheers!

Comment: Here is the setting I was looking for, at least in Eclipse.  Can't find it yet in Aptana 3: Preferences > PHP > Content Assist Then tick the box for "Show variables in other files"

Comment: Here is the setting I was looking for, at least in Eclipse.  Can't find it yet in Aptana 3: Preferences > PHP > Content Assist Then tick the box for "Show variables in other files"  I have not found the equivalent setting in Aptana 3 yet. I did try your suggestions with Aptana 3. I even reinstalled Aptana and I created a brand new project.  The list is still empty.  Nothing appears in the log. Still something that Netbeans does that Eclipse does not do; Netbeans also shows what file(s) the same variable is declared in.  I welcome any other suggestions.  I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Did you create an Aptana PHP project to work at, or do you use a different type of project?
Most of the advanced functionalities require the `PHP Nature` and the `PHP Builder` to be defined for the project. You can either create your project with the Aptana PHP project wizard, or migrate your project to have the `PHP Nature` by right clicking the project- > Select `Project Natures` and the select the `PHP` item (has an icon next to it). Let me know if that did the trick.

Comment: Quote"You can either create your project with the Aptana PHP project wizard..."  Worked THIS time :) I did go into the folder and delete all hidden files (MAC) Quote"or migrate your project to have the PHP Nature by right clicking the project- > Select Project Natures and the select the PHP item (has an icon next to it)." => This I do not see.  No section in the list to migrate a "nature".  I guess I am missing that one.  Again, I am on a MAC.  Would this be why I am not seeing this here?  Thank you ! :)

Comment: Ah!  Right click the project > Project Info > Project Nature > Tick the PHP box!  THAT seems to work also now.  Now the list is picking up the vars with both the new project, (if I delete any existing hidden files and let them be recreated), or, by this method I just outlined in this comment.  Last question:  What is the best way to submit feed back on functionality beyond what we just did here?  Thanks!

Comment: You can always create an issue at http://jira.appcelerator.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa